# Call a repo method in my Symfony command

Tags: php, symfony

I am junior and I am learning Symfony2, my problem is:

I have a repository class with methods and I want call this method in my command class. How can I do that?

This is the repository method:

```
public function findAllStatusToDo(Library $library = null)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('l');

    $qb->select('l, COUNT(l) licenses')
        ->andWhere("l.status = :status")
        ->setParameter(':status', XMLReport::STATUS_ToDo)
        ->addGroupBy('l.library')
        ->addGroupBy('l.isbn');

    if ($library instanceof Library) {
        $qb->andWhere("l.library = :library")->setParameter(':library', $library->getCode());
    }

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

And this is the command class:

```
class GenerateXMLCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('reports:generateXML')
            ->setDescription('Generate XML');
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {

    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `execute()` command you simply need to get the `doctrine` service from the container and then call your repository method like this:

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $container  = $this->getContainer();
    $em         = $container->get('doctrine')->getManager();

    $statusToDo = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:MyRepository')->findAllStatusToDo();
}
```

Just make sure that you call the proper repository in place of `AppBundle:MyRepository` in the above code.